# Generator & Iterators - Iterable [MDN Documentation]

Tags: javascript, iterable

When I read about iterators and generator in MDN. I read some paragraph in there and I don't understand what exactly this mean? Anyone can help me what is this paragraph mean exactly?

> It may be possible to iterate over an iterable more than once, or only
>   once. It is up to the programmer to know which is the case. Iterables
>   which can iterate only once (e.g. Generators) customarily return this
>   from their @@iterator method, where those which can be iterated many
>   times must return a new iterator on each invocation of @@iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this example:

```js
function iterateTwice(iterable) {
    for (const x of iterable) console.log(1, x);
    for (const x of iterable) console.log(2, x);
}

console.log("array");
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
iterateTwice(array);

console.log("generator");
function* makeGenerator() {
    yield 'a'; yield 'b'; yield 'c';
}
const generator = makeGenerator();
iterateTwice(generator);
```

This is because `array[Symbol.iterator]()` returns a new iterator every time that iterates the array from start to end, while `generator[Symbol.iterator]()` returns the same iterator object<sup>[1]</sup> every time. The first `for … of` iteration did exhaust it, the second loop will see and ended iterator that doesn't produce any items.

<sub>1: actually itself, `generator === generator[Symbol.iterator]()`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for comment. I understand what documentation mean. In there problem documentation say "this" and this is make confusing. I think someone must update documentation.

Comment: You mean the part "*customarily return this from their @@iterator method*"? It should read `return this`, because that's exactly how the `generator[Symbol.iterator]` method is implemented to return the `generator` object itself (which is an iterator).

Comment: Yeah I know what U say but I think this is hard to understand without someone's help. Because documentation not say before generator(iterator) have [Symbol.iterator] property. I think they must add some example.

Answer (score 1):

It means, you could create a generator as you want. For example this `eternity` is returning the elements forever.

Be carefull, if you use something like `[...eternity(array)]`.

```js
function* eternity(array) {
    while (true) yield* array;
}

var array = [1, 2, 3],
    gen = eternity(array);

console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
```

Comment: Yeah I know we can make any type generator. Actually I don't understand what mean this part "Iterables which can iterate only once (e.g. Generators) customarily return this from their @@iterator method"

Answer (score 1):

First of all

> There is no @@iterator function,  you have to use Symbol.iterator to implement iteration .

Now as you see the article discusses `generators` and `iterable` at the same time, that's because **generators are iterable**, and implement iteration behavior for a custom object could get describe with generators. Let's take a look at the MDN example :

```
var myIterable = {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
        yield 3;
    }
}

for (let value of myIterable) { 
    console.log(value); 
}
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

It creates iteration overobject with exact 3 itrates.

Writing the same iterable without using generators could explain it more about

> return this from their @@iterator method

```
let range = {
  from: 1,
  to: 3,

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    this.current = this.from;
    return this;
  },

  next() {
    if (this.current <= this.to) {
      return { done: false, value: this.current++ };
    } else {
      return { done: true };
    }
  }
};

for (let num of range) {
  console.log(num); // 1, 2, 3
}
```

Comment: Yeah I understand what U mean but in there this part "Iterables which can iterate only once (e.g. Generators) customarily return this from their @@iterator method" hard understand for me.

Comment: To make it more clear know that It’s impossible to have two for..of loops running over the object simultaneously: they’ll share the iteration state because there’s only one iterator – **the object itself** . that's the **this** that we return from iterable at each iteration.

Comment: In the bellow comment @Bergi ansüer my question correctly. If U wantU can look him answer and thank U for help :)

Comment: It means that you can write an iterator which always returns the same value like `yield 1; yield 2; ..` or you can write an iterattor which doesn't, like current time and all the following minutes.